# Positioning search bar on header

Tags: css

I am having a logo and search bar on header. Logo is on the left corner. I want the search bar at the center of the header. What ever i try its half hidden in the navigation menu. Here is a rough [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmpm/yaqxpm8e/1/)

```
#header  {
    position:relative; 
    float:left; 
    clear:both; 
    width:100%; 
    height:110px; 
    background:url("resources/images/logo.jpg") repeat-y; 
    font-size:30px;
    background:#ccc;
    }

#header img {
    position:relative; 
    left:20px; 
    top:13px; 
    border:0;
}

#header-search {
    position:relative; 
    left:220px; 
}
```

Comment: You mean you want something like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/yaqxpm8e/3/

Comment: No i want at the center of the header

Comment: Oh...like this - http://jsfiddle.net/yaqxpm8e/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Using `float` to both `#header img` & `#header-search` with additional `margin` to customise the spacings.

```
#header  {
    position:relative; 
    float:left; 
    clear:both; 
    width:100%; 
    height:110px; 
    background:url("resources/images/logo.jpg") repeat-y; 
    font-size:30px;
    background:#ccc;
    }

#header img {
    position:relative; 
    left:20px; 
    top:13px; 
    border:0;
    float: left;
}

#header-search {
    position:relative; 
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaqxpm8e/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to follow the css `float` concept for this. I have updated your fiddle based on my understanding. Have a look at it.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/yaqxpm8e/4/

```
#header .logo {
    float: left;
}

#header-search {
    float: left;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managing this without magic numbers can be achieved using a combination of floats and inline block

```css
#header {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    height:110px;
    background:url("resources/images/logo.jpg") repeat-y;
    font-size:30px;
    background:#ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
#header a {
    float: left;
    margin: 13px;    
    /* doesn't quite calculate (110-85)/2 = 12.5 */
}
#header-search {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 35px; /* (110-40)/2 = 35px */
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"> <a href="login.html"><img  src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-200-85-4.jpg" 
      width="200" height="85" /></a> 
    <div id="header-search">
        <form id="searchForm" action="searchproduct.json">Product Name:
            <input type="text" name="productName" value="${product.productName}" id="productName" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note - this method maintains the centered div responsively until the header is too narrow to support it. then you would need media queries.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yaqxpm8e/7/)